# Inserir id no data-formid="" vindo do jquery

Tags: jquery

Preciso incluir no formulário em **data-formid=""** o id de cada evento clicado, para que seja diferente e dar u submit com o ajax em cada formulário.

Eu já consegui passar o id dessa maneira:

Html

```
<div id="eventID_faturar"></div>
```

Jquery

Essa linha é onde pego o id - **$('#eventID_faturar').text(event.id);**

```
eventClick:  function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                endtime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end).format('h:mm');
                starttime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY, h:mm');
                var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
                var mywhen2 = event.id;
                $('#modalTitle_excluir').html(event.title);
                $('#modalWhen_excluir').text(mywhen);
                $('#eventID_faturar').text(event.id);
                $('#calendarModal_excluir').modal();
            }
```

Resultado

```
<div id="eventID_faturar">969</div>
```

Mas eu precisaria incluir esse id no formulário em **data-formid=""**, como eu faria isso

```
<form class="faturar_ajax" data-formid="id_aqui" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">   
<input type="hidden" id="eventID_faturar" name="eventID_faturar"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#eventID_faturar').data('formid', event.id);
```

Mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309926/how-to-get-the-data-id-attribute)

EDIT: o AP quer colocar o valor dentro da tag `form`. Fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$('form:eq(0)').data('formid', <valor a passar>);
```

Onde `form:eq(0)` designa o 1o. `form` na página e `<valor a passar>`, o valor do atributo `data-formid`.

EDIT 2: o AP estava conferindo se o atributo aparecia no DOM e para isso mudamos de `jQuery.data('formid', <valor>)` para `jQuery.attr('data-formid', <valor>)`.

Comment: E no formulário faço como para colocar o id em data-formid=""?

Comment: Se o seu jQuery tiver versão acima ou igual a 1.6.4, o `jQuery.data(<parametro>)` põe e lê do atributo HTML `data-<parametro>`

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi, coloquei meu form assim mas não veioo id em data-formid=""   <form class="faturar_ajax" data-formid="" id="eventID_faturar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: estou usando o jQuery v3.3.1

Comment: Editei a resposta. Favor conferir se atende suas necessidade e caso atenda, aceitar minha resposta e pontuar.

Comment: sim entendi, mas como falei anteriormente, ainda nao deu certo, meu form está assim <form class="faturar_ajax" data-formid="" id="eventID_faturar" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> e meu jquery assim  $('#eventID_faturar').data('formid', event.id);

Comment: Cara, veja o EDIT, fazendo o favor.

Comment: Sim deixei meu jquery assim $('form:eq(0)').data('formid', event.id); mais ainda não veio o id n data-formid=""

Comment: Faça `$('form:eq(0)').data('formid', 12345);` e veja se aparece algo. Se aparecer, o problema é no `event.id`.

Comment: Fiz como vc falour e não aparceu o id ainda o event.id está funcionando pois como falei na pergunta, assim funciona  $('#eventID_faturar').text(event.id); mas fica dentro de uma div e quero que o id fique em data-formid=""

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88869/discussion-between-marcelo-uchimura-and-wagner).